# Which data types are allowed to return from wcf web service

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I am very new in wcf web service ...... I want to know which data types are allowed to return from wcf web service. for example can I return an object from method .....

Comment: you can return an object as long as that object is serializable and does not reference itself

Comment: Anything that can be represented in an XML schema - any "atomic" type in .NET, any compound type based on those atomic types etc. - **however:** XML schema does **NOT** properly support ***generics*** nor ***interfaces***.

Comment: so whats the problem in this ......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545554/object-is-not-returned-from-the-wcf-web-service

Comment: Did you try the answer this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15547688/745969 - to your previous question?